# Assumptions of Error Term: $E[u]=0$

Tags: statistics, intuition, least-squares, linear-regression, expected-value

In a simple linear regression model, expectation of $u$ is taken to be $0$. Why is that?

Can anyone please verify if the explanation I have given below is valid?

Suppose $y= \beta_0 + \beta_1x +u$ acurately models the relationship between $x$ and $y$. Then, we want to model the relationship between $x$ and $y$ keeping all other factors fixed. To do so, we create a simple linear regression model such that $\hat{y} = \hat{\beta_0} +\hat{\beta_1}x$

Now, $\beta_o \ne \hat{\beta_o}$, as now, our $\hat{\beta_0}$ also accounts for the average of the error term. **Are we using the average of the error term to allow for a linear relationship? Because average would be just a number and would allow us to have a linear model?** Then, since the average of the error term which doesn't necessarily have to be 0 is being accounted for in our fitted line, we can safely assume that $E[u]=0$

Is the aforementioned reasoning valid? Please let me know if I have made any conceptual error or if I'm missing anything that provides better understanding.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can always define $u\equiv y-\beta_0-\beta_1x$ so if no assumption is made about $u$, $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ carry no meaning.

Second, the idea behind the assumptioin $E(u)=0$ is that you're saying **on average**, the prediction $\beta_0+\beta_1x$ is correct. That is, suppose there are $n$ independent instances of the observations $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$, then we would like that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\beta_0+\beta_1x_i-y_i)$ converges almost surely to $0$.

Third, once you assume that there are some $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ such that $E(y-\beta_0-\beta_1x)=0$, you can move on to the business of the estimation. If you're willing to assume further that $E[x(y-\beta_0-\beta_1x)]=0$ then you can least squares. If not, then something else (IV, GMM) is appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'd like to know when we say $E[u]=0$, are we also implying that in our linear regression model, the term $\hat{\beta_o}$ would contain in itself the average value of all the other factors influencing y which may not be zero?

Comment: @A.Asad There are 2 separate things here: the assumption $E(u)$ is about $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$. Whether $\beta_0$ is a reasonable estimator of $\beta_0$ depends on how you estimate it and if you're willing to make **further** assumption(s) about model.

Comment: Oh! So the average is contained within the $\beta_o$ and $u$ is essentially just random and should its $E[u] \ne 0$, this would have implied that there is a systematic relationship between $y$ and $u$ which can be captured and a better model can be constructed? Am i right now?

Comment: @A.Asad $\beta_0$ in this case is a number so it doesn't make sense to talk about "the average" "contained within". $u$ on the other hand can be thought of as the error in prediction: $u=y-(\beta_0+\beta_1x)$. So $E(u)$ says that **on average** the model does not have a prediction error. p.s. In the previous comment, I should have said "Whether $\hat\beta_0$ is a reasonable estimator of ..."

Comment: But the average of all other variables affecting $y$ would also be a number, no?

Comment: Also, apologies for taking up so much of your time asking these questions; Really grateful to you!

Comment: @A.Asad The average of the prediction errors is a random variable. When the number of observations increases, you would hope that this average converges to $0$. This is the motivation behind assuming $E(u)=0$.

Comment: Can you please have a look at this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2944479/490979 I'm in desperate need of the answer... thank you!